# Make a stream to generate the multiples of three

Tags: java, loops, lambda, stream

I'm trying to generate a stream of integers, so i make a static method that return a Stream

Here you can found the method:

```java
public static Stream<Integer> multipleOf3(){
    return Stream.iterate(1, x -> 3*x).limit(10);
}
```

However this method don't return me the mutitple of three but the power of three

i call the method like that:

```java
multipleDe3().forEach(System.out::println);
```

and i have this result:

```
1
3
9
27
81
243
729
2187
6561
19683
```

I think the iterate function use the previous result, the seeds = 1, so x = 1 and then:

```
3*1 = 3, 
3*3 = 9, 
3*9 = 27, etc...
```

So if anyone has an idea to calculate the multiple without use the previous result tell me please

Comment: Create a stream of consecutive integers and map them with .map(i -> i * 3).

Comment: Change `3*x` to `3+x`. Remember, multiplication is essentially just how many times you _add_ a number. Adding `3` to the previous value is necessarily the next multiple of `3`, assuming the previous value was itself a multiple of `3`.

Comment: @Slaw with x+3 i have 1, 4, 7, .. but if i change the seeds to start with 0 that's work thank you

Comment: @Torben It's good idea but i need to change the prototype of method, Stream<Integer> becomes Stream and some error come when i compile :

`java: non-static method <R>map(java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends R>) cannot be referenced from a static context `

Comment: Note it would make more sense to use an `IntStream` than a `Stream<Integer>`. Everything else could remain the same: `IntStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 3).skip(1).limit(10)`

Comment: ah IntStream i did not think about it, it is indeed a better alternative, thank you Torben and Slaw

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've implemented Torben's suggestion in the wrong way if you get that error. An `IntStream` might be better but even a `Stream<Integer>` should work: `Stream.iterate(1, x -> x+1).map(i -> i * 3)`.

Comment: yes, I think so, now i have multiple solution and i understand the trink of `IntStream` thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Stream<Integer> multipleOf3(){
    return Stream.iterate(0, x -> 3+x).skip(1).limit(10);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    multipleOf3().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output :
3
6
9
12
15
18
21
24
27
30

Comment: skip(1) is used to skip the first element in the stream , if you like to see the 0 in your result stream remove the skip(1) , welcome

Comment: `Stream.iterate(3, x -> 3 + x).limit(10)` also works.